# Spacing of resonant modes in a (laser) cavity

Tags: optics, harmonic-oscillator, laser, fourier-transform

I don't see why the frequency spacing between resonant cavity modes should decrease with higher frequency. Here's what I have:

For a laser cavity of length $L$, from the condition of constructive interference during a roundtrip

$$e^{-i 2\omega \frac{L}{c}}=e^{-i 2 \pi q}$$

we get the possible resonance frequencies inside the cavity as

$$\omega=q \cdot 2\pi \cdot \frac{c}{2L}$$

with an integer $q$

**The resonance frequencies (axial modes) are thus equidistantly spaced in the frequency domain**

$$\Delta \omega=2\pi \cdot \frac{c}{2L}$$

However, in [Siegman's Lasers](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Lasers.html?id=1BZVwUZLTkAC&redir_esc=y) on Page 499, this frequency distribution is illustrated and described as

> **Frequency Distribution of Resonant Cavity Modes**
>
> [image]
>
> Suppose we consider some arbitrary shaped (...) cavity having closed
>   and completely reflecting walls. Let us then calculate all the
>   theoretically possible lowest and higher-order electromagnetic modes
>   in this cavity; and plot the resonant frequencies (...) as tic marks
>   in the frequency scale.
>
> **As we go to higher frequencies, where the cavity dimensions become large compared to the resonance wavelengths, these resonant modes
>   become more and more closely spaced along the frequency axis.**

No formula is given for this decrease in spacing. I could not find any derivation in the chapters that preceded this illustration and argument. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it's showing $\omega$ on a log scale.

Comment: No, I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: that sure looks like logarithmic scale to me

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the section referenced is referring to the modes of a *linear* (1D) optical resonator but, rather, the modes of a 'volume' resonator analogous to the acoustic resonances in my home theater (sigh).

In such an acoustic 3D resonator, the modes are distinguished by three numbers, $n_x,\,n_y,\,n_z$ indicating the order of the mode in each of the three dimensions and the frequency of the mode is proportional to

$$f_{n_xn_yn_z} \propto \sqrt{\left(\frac{n_x}{L_x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{n_y}{L_y}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{n_z}{L_z}\right)^2}$$

and so the frequency spacing does *decrease* with *increasing* order.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because the cavity resonances occur when the length is an integer multiple of *wavelength*. Since $\omega=2\pi c/\lambda$, then you see the spacing decrease as 1/$\lambda$ in frequency.